# JqueryUi slider range doesn't apear after async call

Tags: jquery-ui, slider

I have 2 pages, let's say page1.php and page2.php
In page2.php i have the JqueryUI slider range (ex.http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/range.html)
If I open this page in browser it works fine, but if I try to call this page from page1.php with ajax async the slider does not shown.

I know I have to reinitialize the slider on client side...  but how?
I tried to eval the http response but... nothing:(

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the slider on page 2? You might need to wrap the code that initializes the slider in a function that you can call when you do the AJAX load.